# How to handle twilio exceptions by error code and process them

Tags: python, exception, twilio

I am using the following approach for handling Twilio exceptions in Python:

```
try:
    #code for sending the sms
    print(message.sid)
except TwilioRestException as e:
    print(e)
```

This allows me to send sms and Exceptions are handled by Python.

Now I need to "return" the exceptions codes in order to process them, let's say, give user a message depending on the exception.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If raising exception is not an option you could simply add return under except block.

```
def func():
    # your logic
    try:
        #code for sending the sms
        print(message.sid)
    except TwilioRestException as e:
        print(e)
        return e.code  # or whetever attribute e has for it...
```

By default function will return `None` if everything goes right. In client code it will be like

```
err = func()
if err:
    # sms wasn't sent, action required
```